# Dereferencing a ref inside a function yields different results. Why?

Tags: f#

In this sample, get_final_answer is being eagerly evaluated, and always returns 0.0.  I thought expressions containing refs were treated differently (and not eagerly evaluated in this case) due to their inherently mutable characteristics.  I expected it to return 7.0.

```
let FinalAnswer = ref 0.0
let get_final_answer = !FinalAnswer

let rec eval_expr_fail =
        FinalAnswer := 7.0
        get_final_answer        // fails, returns 0.0

let rec eval_expr_works =
        FinalAnswer := 7.0
        !FinalAnswer           // works, return 7.0
```

How do I dereference FinalAnswer outside the block where I updated it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_final_answer` in `let get_final_answer = !FinalAnswer` is a float value, not a function. It is the value of 0.0, and has nothing to do with `FinalAnswer` once the value is assigned.

Making it as a function gets what you want:

```
let FinalAnswer = ref 0.0
let get_final_answer() = !FinalAnswer

let rec eval_expr_fail =
        FinalAnswer := 7.0
        get_final_answer ()       //  returns 7.0
```

Comment: Functions are values too! You mean "is a float, not a function".